# Symfony login not working for multiple firewalls with same pattern

Tags: php, regex, security, symfony

I have a question regarding symfony security.

My security.yml is setup as follows:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        OVB\DBBundle\Entity\User\User:
            id: ovb.password.encoder

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    test:  { password: ******, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        main:
            entity:
                class: OVB\DBBundle\Entity\User\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            provider: in_memory
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Test Area"
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path:         /login
                check_path:         ovb_login_check
                use_referer:        true
            logout:                 true
            anonymous:              ~
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login_check, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

As you can see I have 2 firewalls with the same pattern. The first (secured_area) is to protect my testing environment (HTTP Authentication), the second is for regular website users (form login).
Individually they both work, but together they don't, I think it's the fact that they use the same pattern.
Does anyone know a way of making this work?

Thank you!

Comment: why are you creating 2 firewalls with the same pattern?

Comment: Like i said, the first one (secured_area) is specifically meant for my development environment, I don't want other people to be able to access it. But I would still like to be able to test regular user login on this environment. When the website goes live, i'll remove the 'secured_area' firewall

Comment: Does this admin user uses the website the same way a `OVB\DBBundle\Entity\User\User` does ?

Comment: The admin user (or test user) is to be able to access the whole website. The normal user is there specifically for like posting stuff and changing information on the website. So no, for now (on the testing environment) the admin user is needed to go to the website, the normal user is not needed (only for posting to the website)

Comment: Isn't the admin user using the standard log-in form a better alternative ?

Comment: @user2465090 What do you get as error?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I've encountered very similar situation so I'm wondering what to do :).

Comment: @Martin I never solved it, but I solved it by not requiring user login on dev environment and just using http authentication there. Check my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In your base `security.yml`:

```
security:

    #...

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class:    'OVB\DBBundle\Entity\User\User'
                property: email

        dev:
           memory:
               users:
                   admin: { password: ******, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    firewalls:        
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path:         /login
                check_path:         ovb_login_check
                use_referer:        true
            logout:                 true
            anonymous:              ~
```

---

In your `security_dev.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            http_basic:
                provider: dev
```

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what i want, but it did give me another idea that works. I set the 'secured_area' firewall in the default security.yml file and the main one in the dev security file and let it overwrite the 'secured_area' firewall.